# How to size text in an SVG element

Tags: css, svg, powerapps, viewbox

I am trying to put text inside SVG so we can use custom fonts in PowerApps

Sp I have an image with the below definition in the **Image** property (I've cut out the *Base 64 font definition of about 1000 lines*:

```
"data:image/svg+xml," & // You need to include this data uri to indicate that the code herein is an SVG image
 EncodeUrl(
    "<svg viewBox='0 0 1291 338' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <style>
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'BHF Beats';
    src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABAAAAAFHUAA8AAAAA21AAAFFyAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
{TL:DR}
4q/Jed/AdY8h4kAAHjaY2BgYGQAgqtL1DlA9LU2kwwYDQA7fwWaAAA=) format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

    .BHFBeats { font: 128px BHF Beats;fill: white }
  </style>

  <text x='21' y='180' class='BHFBeats'>ExpenSys Claimant Setup Administration Module</text>
</svg>"
)
```

with those settings this is what I can see (in PowerApps Studio:

[image]

but what I am trying to achieve is similar to what we can get using a simple *Label* control as below:

[image]

so what I want is the text to be the right size, and start at the far-left, and show **all the text**

I've tried many different settings for font size, view-box size but cannot get it right...

Where am I going wrong?

More info:
The *label* control in the second image has a height of **50** and a width if **823**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `preserveAspectRatio` attribute to your SVG.

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet" ...
```

It will ensure the contents of your SVG always start at the left end of the parent container.

**Update**

For example.  With and without the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
}

svg {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 1291 338" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
      .BHFBeats { font: 128px "BHF Beats";fill: white }
    </style>

    <text x="21" y="180" class="BHFBeats">ExpenSys Claimant Setup Administration Module</text>
  </svg>

</div>


<br/><br/>


<div>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 1291 338" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMid meet">
    <style>
      .BHFBeats { font-size: 128px; fill: white }
    </style>

    <text x="21" y="180" class="BHFBeats">ExpenSys Claimant Setup Administration Module</text>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: @PaulLebau: Thanks, how do we set the `xMinYMid`?

Comment: Sorry. There was a typo in my example attribute.  I've fixed it now and added an example.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I removed the `ViewBox` attribute, added the `preserveAspectRatio` and it now works...

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio` attribute only applies to SVGs that have a `viewBox`.  If the SVG meets your needs without the viewBox, then you can safely remove the `preserveAspectRatio` also.

Answer (score 2):

I would calculate the size of the text using javascript like so:

```js
let font_size = 128;

// while the text length is bigger than needed 
  while(txt.getComputedTextLength() > 1291 - 21 ){//1291 is the width of the svg canvas taken fron the viewBox. 21 is the offset of the text as in `x="21"`
    //reduce the font size
    font_size -=.25;
    //reset the font size 
    txt.style.fontSize = font_size+"px";
  }
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 1291 338' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <style>
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'BHF Beats';
    src: url(data:application/font-woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABAAAAAFHUAA8AAAAA21AAAFFyAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
{TL:DR}
4q/Jed/AdY8h4kAAHjaY2BgYGQAgqtL1DlA9LU2kwwYDQA7fwWaAAA=) format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

    .BHFBeats { font: 128px BHF Beats;fill: white }
  </style>

  <text id="txt" x='21' y='180' class='BHFBeats'>ExpenSys Claimant Setup Administration Module</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer but unfortunately we cannot use JavaScript in PowerApps (sucks I know)